# Execute /bin script from other python script

Tags: python

I have a script in my project's bin directory, and I want to execute it from a cron. Both scripts are written in python.

Target file :

```
App_directory/bin/script_name
```

Want to execute `script_name` script with some parameters from `App_directory/cron/script_name1.py`

How do I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me...

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen('script_name')
print process.communicate()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
import os
os.system('/path/to/App_directory/bin/script_name')
```

Or if `script_name` is not executable and/or doesn't have the shabang (`#!/usr/bin/env python`):

```
import os
os.system('python /path/to/App_directory/bin/script_name')
```

Comment: I have shabang #! /usr/bin/env python in script_name file

Comment: -1: Please use `subprocess`.  See this: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system.

Answer (score 2):

The subprocess module is much better than using os.system. Just do:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['/path/to/App_directory/bin/script_name'])
```

The subprocess.call function returns the returncode (exit status) of the script.